# C get numeric value from part of string

Tags: c, string, int, long-integer, strtol

My task is to get `long` numeric value from part of `char[]`, where I have the index of its begining and ending.  I am just learning C, so it is confusing to me which function works the best in my case..

Lets say im making function `getNum()`:

```
static char words[100000]; //lets say this is string filled  with many num. values and other stuff.  

long getNum(int begin, int end){
 return (long){part of string starting at words[begin] and ending at words[end]}    
}
```

I would like to know the best method and easiest method to do this. Any other comments are much appreciated too.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not counting the `code` in question as real effort.

Comment: Take a look at `atoi`. [LINK](http://www.codingunit.com/c-reference-stdlib-h-function-atoi-convert-a-string-to-an-integer)

Comment: @SouravGhosh too minimal for a minute of you time ://?

Comment: @hou the problem is that you are asking for a complete solution. Try yourself to do something, and then we can correct or suggest something. This is not a free of charge coding service....

Comment: @hou Sorry again, but I see no reason for your sarcasm.  Please read [ask] before posting question. Thank you. :-)

Comment: I had several options to chose from. One would be making new char[end-begin], other would be sscanf, another strtol and probably few more that I am not aware of. I wanted to know which would be the most optmal, with the least code. Such suggestion would help me alot for this task. Knowing the best way would help me in future tasks for sure. Thats why im asking for advice

Comment: @hou that you shouled have mentioned in the question body itself, not in the comment. Otherwise, it looks like you are _asking_ for a ready-made solutions.

Comment: And, just to add, there can be _various_ ways to achieve the same, depeneding on the structure of the actual _string_ `words`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We give the algorithm, you write the code. Agree?

OK, so the logic should be

1. create an array of `char`s based on the `end-start+1` index range.
2. do a [`memcpy()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memcpy) from the source to the new array fro the `end-start` size.
3. null-terminate the array.
4. use [`strtol()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol) to convert the *array* to numeric value.

Answer (score 0):

I realized I don't need index of the end of numeric value.

So far following solution seems the easiest:

```
static char words[100000]; //lets say this is string filled  with many num. values and other stuff.  
static char *endp;

long getNum(int begin){
 return strtol(&words[begin], &endp, 10);    
}
```

Sourav Ghosh's solution above to include use of ending index

Comment: Post examples of data input.

Comment: This is wrong. don't take the `end` as the _end-of_string_for_conversion_. Read the manual page I linked properly.

Comment: @chux I think the local `end` will shadow the global `end`. :-)

Comment: Oh yeah I have misstyped actuall program into this example. fixed  
Also I have realized, that in my case I dont need the ending index, since I want it to read till first non-nummeric char. I should have though of that earlier. My bad